# Is it possible for rsyslog to create a directory?

Tags: rsyslog

## The Setup

I have this in my `/etc/rsyslog.conf`:

```
$template local1DynFile,"/path/to/my/log/%programname%.log.%NOW%
$template local1LogFormat,"%msg:2:$:%\n"

*,*;auth,authpriv,local0,local1.none          ~/var/log/syslog

local1.*                                      ?local1DynFile;local1LogFormat
```

Then I have the following Python script (`test.py`):

```
import logging
import logging.handlers

logger = logging.getLogger('pxet.foo')
logger.addHandler(logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(address='/run/systemd/journal/syslog', facility='local1'))
logger.handlers[0].setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

logger.debug('test cockroach is a bug')
```

## The Problem

If I do the following:

```
rm -rf /path/to/my/log
systemctl restart rsyslog
python test.py
```

I get no log message. However:

```
mkdir -p /path/to/my/log
python test.py
```

And it all works.

## The Question

Is it possible for me to make `rsyslog` create the directories if they do not exist, or do I have to do that myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation (http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/action/index.html#omfile-specific-configuration-statements) says that rsyslog has the `$CreateDirs` legacy configuration option to control whether or not to create directories an as needed. (There is a similarly named option `CreateDirs` for the next configuration format, but your example uses the legacy format.) So try the line:

`$CreateDirs on`

just before your

`local1.*                                      ?local1DynFile;local1LogFormat`

line.

Comment: Perfect! There was much googling (e.g. `rsyslog create directory`) to no avail. It would appear that Centos7 comes with rsyslog v7 (i.e. legacy config)... but adding that to my config works.